# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to open links?

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I have tried using this `WL.App.openURL('link','_blank')`.

In my app, I have some hyperlinks. Upon clicking a link, it has to load respective pages in the app itself.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-using the API...

You have 2 options:

1. Use [Cordova's InAppBrowser API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

   This way you can display a browser window ontop of the app; when done you tap a button to close it and return to the app. This code snippet works:

   > ```
   > <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes')">visit Apache.org</a>;
   > ```
2. Read the [Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_07_Integrating_server_generated_pages_in_Worklight_applications.pdf) training module and inspect the [sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/IntegratingServerGeneratedPagesProject.zip)

   This way you can load an external URL within the application's WebView.

---

For your case option 1 seems the solution to use.

Comment: When you say "iphone", do you mean the iOS Simulator? physical device? preview in Worklight Console?

Comment: One more help needed regarding hyperlinks..if suppose i have to use <a href="mailto:konetikiran@gmail.com">kiran</a> on click of this can i open mail application in the iPhone?

Comment: You start by not asking new questions in comments; then you search StackOverflow for a similar quetion. This should work: <a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'mailto:an@email.address?subject=My Subject Line'">Send email</a>

Comment: Yes sure.it is Displaying error as Fail to load webpage with error :The URL cant be shown in iPhone