# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to open https links?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to Worklight and building the application for a client.

I tried using [IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to open links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075184/ibm-worklight-6-1-how-to-open-links)

but not able to it so for https links. However, I searched other links but could 
not get the answer.

In the sample project if I modify the IBM link with https link I go not get Overlay response:

```
IncludeExternalPages.thisapp.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                IncludeExternalPages.clearWebViewOverlayHistory();
                Log.d("IncludeExternalPages", "opening link :: ");
                IncludeExternalPages.loadWebViewOverlay("http://m.ibm.com");
                Log.d("IncludeExternalPages", "opened link :: 1");
                IncludeExternalPages.setWebViewOverlayVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                IncludeExternalPages.requestWebViewOverlayFocus();
                IncludeExternalPages.clearWebViewOverlayHistory();
            }
        });
```

Output from LogCat is:

```
D/NONE(3983): after: app init onSuccess
D/NONE(3983): added onPause event handler 
D/NONE(3983): wlclient init success
D/IncludeExternalPages(3983): webViewOverlay is openning :: http://m.ibm.com/in/
D/IncludeExternalPages(3983): webViewOverlay is openning :: http://m.ibm.com/in/en/
D/CordovaActivity(3983): Paused the application!
D/CordovaWebView(3983): Handle the pause
```

The above overlay response comes as below when I change IBM link to https link:

```
D/NONE(3042): after: app init onSuccess
D/NONE(3042): added onPause event handler 
D/NONE(3042): wlclient init success
D/dalvikvm(3042): GC_CONCURRENT freed 942K, 27% free 7523K/10183K, paused 13ms+24ms, total 58ms
D/CordovaActivity(3042): Paused the application!
D/CordovaWebView(3042): Handle the pause
```

Comment: Thanks Manu for the edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot confirm what you're saying...
You do not mention what is the URL you are trying to load, so I cannot help further.

1. I've used the [Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/IntegratingServerGeneratedPagesProject.zip) sample project  in Worklight 6.1.0.1
2. I've edited the URL in android/native/src/com/IncludeExternalPages/WebViewOverlayPlugin.java

   From:

   ```
   IncludeExternalPages.loadWebViewOverlay("http://m.ibm.com/");
   ```

   To:

   ```
   IncludeExternalPages.loadWebViewOverlay("https://www.facebook.com/");
   ```

   Launched in the Android Emulator and could see Facebook's secure login page...
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Idan!! I expected a reply from you :). You are correct after posting here I tried other https links and were working but not mine. I could not write the complete URL but the url is like https://<domain>:<port>/<XYZ>/index.html. Is the problem related to the rendering? I am able to open URL on mobile in other ways but not  through external link as mentioned...